# How to prevent a form submission if another user changed the same entity object?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to prevent a submission, if another user have changed the same entity object that is used by this form.

If I check the entity variable "changed" before

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {}
```

in the Controller, the variable has always the latest **timestamp**. Means someone else has already changed this entity. So I can't compare changed.

Thank you for your help

Controller:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    $x = $product->getChanged();

    dump($x); // I will get the latest timestamp

    $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();

        dump($data);
        // exit;

        $data->setChanged(); // Set to test if life circle method preUpdate/prePersist is removed

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($data);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect(...);
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Product:test.html.twig', array( // twig just contain {{ form(form) }}
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Entity:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * ...
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     */
    protected $changed;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function updateTimestamp()
    {
        $this->setChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Set changed
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setChanged()
    {
        $this->changed = new \DateTime();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can pass timestamp in form (as hidden field) and then compare this with value in database. Of course this can be easily cracked so you should generate some kind of token and verify it on backend

Comment: I did this but it is alway the latest timestamp. Even if I save timestamp in session variable before $form->valid - its alway the latest timestamp.

Comment: maybe the problem is that you are updating field in PrePersist state

Comment: I removed PrePersist and PreUpdate, made doctrine:schema:update, cleared cache and do set the timestamp manually before $em->persist($product); in the Controller. And still it's always the latest timestamp (saved by another user) while had opened the form.

Comment: I removed my twig template. Now it's just {{ form(form) }}. And I remove my Product Model, now it's just $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product); And still I get always the latest timestamp.

Comment: Maybe post a bit of your controller code.  handleRequest will update Product::changed from your form data so you need to tuck it away before handleRequest.  From your description, I don't think that is the problem.  Might also want to look at the versionable functionality: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#optimistic-locking

Comment: I posted my Controller. Have the same problem if I use ORM\Version instead of changed.

Comment: Any ideas to fix this problem?